# How to implement image separation using FastICA_2.5.zip

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I use FastICA_2.5.zip from webpage http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/code/dlcode.shtml to do image separation. My code is as following. My expected result is the output image is as same as input, in other words, it can unmix the mixed image to three part. Could you tell me where is wrong? Thank you for you help!

```
I1 = imread('Region1.jpg');//image size as 256*256
I2 = imread('Region2.jpg');//image size as 256*256
I3 = imread('Region3.jpg');//image size as 256*256
s1=reshape(I1,[1,256*256]);       %convert I1 to 1*(256*256) matrix
s2=reshape(I2,[1,256*256]);
s3=reshape(I3,[1,256*256]);
s=[s1;s2;s3];                % Now S is 3*（256*256）
sig=double(s);
Aorig=rand(size(sig,1));  %Aorig is 3*3 matrices
mixedsig=Aorig*sig;       %mixed signal

icasig = fastica (mixedsig, 'approach', 'symm', 'g', 'tanh'); %do fastICA

Is1=reshape(icasig(1,:),[256,256]);
Is2=reshape(icasig(2,:),[256,256]);
Is3=reshape(icasig(3,:),[256,256]);
II1=uint8(round(Is1));
II2=uint8(round(Is2));
II3=uint8(round(Is3));      %显示分离后的图像  
subplot(2,3,4),imshow(II1)
subplot(2,3,5),imshow(II2)
subplot(2,3,6),imshow(II3)
```

because my reputation is very low,so I upload input data in cloud,the link is as following:
[the input image is kept in this website](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1o67LqzC)

Comment: What is `s1` to `s3`?

Comment: I'm sorry, It's a mistake. I have corrected it .